# clickhouse merge one partition at a time

Tags: clickhouse

How do I force ClickHouse to only merge one partition at a time when I run optimize table **** final (without specifying partition 201304 and then 201305 and running it sequentilly) ?

I am using a CollapsingMergeTree. Its using a lot of RAM to do multiple merges together for many partitions and killing the service/machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem of `optimize final` (table or partition does not matter) that it re-writes/re-merges a partition fully even if partition have only 1 part which is excessive in 99.9999% occasions!!!! It re-merges old data which was finally merged already!!!

It needed because sometimes one needs to collapse rows (duplicates) inserted with single insert into partition with forever single part. It is a very very rare necessity.

So I recommend to run optimize final against partitions which have more than one part. You can use something like this

```
select concat('optimize table ',database, '.','\`', table, '\` partition ',partition , ' final;')
from system.parts
where active and (engine like '%ReplacingMergeTree' or  engine like '%CollapsingMergeTree')
group by database,table,partition
having   count()>1
```

PS: If you use GraphiteMergeTree it's another story and there are more simple solutions.

Comment: I am running an optimize table partition by partition its taking a lot of memory(15G). 
I thought merges should take place in a streaming manner? 
is there a setting I could set to upper bound this ?

Comment: @saurabhdaga it's complicated question better to ask in separate question. But anyway there are two types of merges vertical and horizontal. Vertical uses less memory and you can enforce a table to use it. Also it is in streaming manner -- but buffered with 8k rows in a buffer, if you store long Strings - i.e. 10KB -- 10k*8k*16(parts) ~ 1.2GB. You can tune number of rows using merge_max_block_size. Another story AggregatingMT -- states (Uniq - HLL) can be huge 1MB - 10 MB. So it hard to answer without knowing details about your table -- even number of columns does matter.