# ClickHouse - CollapsingMergeTree Table Engine - Records are not merged even if they have same column values and different signs(+1/-1)

Tags: clickhouse

We have a `ClickHouse` table with `CollapsingMergeTree` engine. We want to update the records as and when data is imported from source(May be frequent). Initially all the records are inserted with +1 sign column. What we do to update a record is we insert the record to be updated with same values with -1 sign and then insert an updated record with +1 sign expecting that the same records with opposite signs will be collapsed by `ClickHouse` when data parts are merged in background.

The problem is **'It never happens'**

I am aware of the fact that `ClickHouse` will merge data asynchronously but its been months and no merge is performed by `ClickHouse`.

I queried `SELECT * FROM system.merges` to know if any merges are in progress. Query result was 0. Also updated `ClickHouse` to its latest version. But no luck!

Would appreicate your help if anyone can point out what's the issue? Am I missing on any server level settings? When `ClickHouse` merges such records?

Or any other approach I should be taking to update `ClickHouse` data?

Answer (score 0):

*eventually -- could be never. 
You should not rely on merge process. It has own complicated algorithm to balance number of parts. 
Merge has no goal to do final merge -- to make 1 part because it's not efficient.*

*optimize does / forces unnplaned merge, and you'll get for example 4 parts from 22
optimize final does / forces unnplaned merges for all parts until only one part in partition
The only problem with final that it rewrites even 1 part to a new 1 part. Because sometimes it needed to collapse rows over a single part.
So for some tables we run optimize table x partition final (by crond)  for partitions which have more than one part.*

```
select  concat('optimize table ',database, '.','\`', table, '\` partition ',  ((groupUniqArray(partition)) as partition_count)[1], ' final')
    from system.parts
    where (database = 'xxx' or database like 'zzzz\_%') and (database,table) in (select database, table from system.replicas where engine='ReplicatedReplacingMergeTree' and is_leader)
          and table not like '.inner%' 
    group by database,table having   length(partition_count)>1 and sum(rows) < 5000000
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/60154073/11644308

Comment: Thanks Denis for the response. Can you suggest any other approach to update ClickHouse data?

Comment: replacingMergeTree?

Aggregating mergeTree https://gist.github.com/den-crane/d03524eadbbce0bafa528101afa8f794